# Calling a JS function from a JS-File in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to change colors on my wordpress site in different parts of the site, like header, archiv, etc.

My JS script has some funtions like headerColor(), bodyColor(), titleColor etc.

I tried it like this on my php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "js/change.color.js">
headerColor();
</script>
```

But that seems to be wrong.

Here ar the js functions, they call functions i need at the time:

```
 function headerColor() {
        init();
        changeBackgroundColor();
        changeTextBlackWhite();
    }
    function titleColor() {
        init();
        changeBackgroundColor();
        changeTextBlackWhite();
        changeTiktokIconBlackWhite
    }
```

Comment: What is the error? You may want to include the JS file at the end of your body so that JS has access to the DOM elements

Comment: This seems to be entirely unrelated to PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "js/change.color.js">
headerColor();
</script>
```

is not how to call a function in an external script. the statements inside the script tags which have a src attribute will not be executed

You need two scripts and an event listener

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src= "js/change.color.js"></script>
 <script>window.addEventListener("load",headerColor);</script>
```

the second part CAN be in the external script too